# Replace null value with previous value without using ID in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

It's done with the use of ID but I want without using ID

```
 SELECT
        ID
        ,COALESCE(p.number, 
            (SELECT TOP (1) number 
            FROM tablea AS p2 
            WHERE
                p2.number IS NOT NULL 
                AND p2.ID <= p.ID ORDER BY p2.ID DESC))as Number--,Result = p.number
    FROM TableA AS p;
```

---

```
ID  number
1   100
2   150
3   NULL
4   300
5   NULL
6   NULL
7   450
8   NULL
9   NULL
10  560
11  NULL
12  880
13  NULL
14  579
15  987
16  NULL
17  NULL
18  NULL
```

Comment: `ID` is used to define the order of rows. If you have other columns that define the order, use them. If you don't have such a column - add it. Somehow you need to tell the server what does "previous" row mean.

Comment: We can do with ROW_NUMBER()..But I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. This will help you get your desired result set. This query is written in SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
WITH CTE AS
( SELECT id, number FROM tablea)
SELECT A.id, A.number, ISNULL(A.number,B.number) number
FROM CTE A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM CTE 
WHERE id < a.id AND number IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id DESC) B
```

You can try using LAG and LEAD functions in SQL Server 2012/